# How can i improve/make easier my "pull-up sequence accumulator counter"?

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I wanted to create a function describing a sport game called "Leader". The idea is that you make as many push-ups as you can increasing each repetition by 1 and as you reach your maximum, each next repetition is decreased by 1 until you reach 0 push-ups eventually.

I managed to do this using dictionaries, but I think this could be done in much easier way.

```
def leader_step(max):
    i = 0
    psps = {0: 0}
    k = 1
    cnt = {0:0}
    while max >= psps[i]:
        if psps[i] == max:      # decrease push-ups as they reach max
            k = -1
        i += 1
        psps[i] = k + psps[i-1]
        if psps[i] < 1:         # game stops when you reach 1 push-up
            del psps[i]
            break
        cnt[i] = cnt[i - 1] + psps[i]
    del psps[0]
    del cnt[0]
    return psps.values(), cnt.values()
```

Function should return 2 sequences:
1) showing the number of push-ups at each repetition
2) showing total sum of push-ups made at each repetition

Comment: Ask at [codereview.se]

Comment: You could delete the question